# Unitarity and Legendre polynomials

Tags: quantum-field-theory, universe, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Zohar Komargodski in [these](http://indico.ictp.it/event/7624/session/19/contribution/84/material/0/0.pdf) lecture notes claims:

[image]

I don't understand the requirement about unitarity.

**Why must residues be expressed in terms of Legendre polynomials?**

How does this statement follow from unitarity?